# What is the html font-size base for a design given (1920px x 1080px)?

Tags: css, responsive-design, font-size

I'm a little confused.  If I have a mockup design given (1920x1080px) and for example the paragraph has a font-size of 22px and h1 has a value of 60px, what should be the base of font-size to convert to rem?

```
html {
   font-size: 18px;
}

html {
       font-size: 100%;
    }
```

or should  I take

```
   html {
     font-size: 62.5%
   }
```

Comment: I would do `html { font-size: 62.5%; }` and `body { font-size: 2.2rem; }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If, as @HaoWu suggests, you set

```
html { font-size: 62.5%; }
```

then you are basically setting rem as 10px in most cases because most browsers will default to 16px as the base font size. It’s then an easy calculation to set h1 to 60px as it’s just 6rem.

There will be occasional exceptions if the user has set the browser base size to something else. That is their choice, perhaps because they hope for websites to automatically show bigger text. This means you cannot absolutely depend on 1rem being 10px. In most cases this should be fine as everything will be correctly proportional.

If it is vital to your layout, and usually in a properly responsive design it won’t be, that the rem has a definite px value then you need to define html font-size in px, but best not if you can avoid it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If it is ok to take 62.5% for a 1920x1080px mockup, then for example for devices between 768 and 992 you should have a font size: 50%; and would it be okay?

Comment: I think you’d want to make sure the size didn’t become unreadable so you’d need some sort of test to make sure it didn’t go down too far. I don’t know what is considered unreadable though. Hope someone can answer.

Comment: There’s a readable article here [link] https://css-tricks.com/accessible-font-sizing-explained/ which touches on WCAG, accessibility  guidelines. They seem to be recommending that you use proportional font sizes, as you are, but that you don’t let them go below the browser standard size ( normally 16px). And I have read elsewhere Apple advice that buttons should not be below 44px square.